Devenv doesn't start after adding "serverAliases" to Caddy option in nix file
I use Shopware locally in a Devenv environment. The Shopware admin must be accessed via the license domain, otherwise the plugins with rental licenses will not work.
To do this, the license domain must be entered in the /etc/hosts file.
Now I wanted to use this domain as a server alias in Devenv / with Caddy. Unfortunately, Caddy tells me that the address is already in use during devenv up and the whole process fails.
Relevant excerpt from devenv.nix:
services.caddy = {
    enable = lib.mkDefault true;

    virtualHosts.":8000" = lib.mkDefault {
      serverAliases = [ "license.domain" ];
      extraConfig = ''
        root * public
        php_fastcgi unix/${config.languages.php.fpm.pools.web.socket}
        encode zstd gzip
        file_server
        log {
          output stderr
          format console
          level ERROR
        }
      '';
    };
  };

Does anyone know how I can get the domain to work locally? I need to upgrade to Shopware 6.6.
I am using a Mac by the way.

It sounds like you just have another process listening on port 8000?
